# Como retornar um valor ao invés de uma [object Promise]

Tags: javascript, api, axios

Eu tenho esse código e quero retornar a string não a promise, mas não sei como exatamente como fazer, já tentei olhar outras soluções no site porém não consegui aplicá-las no meu código. (estou usando o axios)

```
async function traduzCategoria(texto)
{
    if (typeof texto === "undefined"){
        return "sem categoria";
    }

    let textoUrl = texto[0].replace(/ /gi, "+");
    textoUrl = texto[0].replace(/&/gi, "and");

    let urlYandex = "https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=" + keyYandex 
        + "&text=" + textoUrl + "&lang=pt";

    let res = await axios.get(urlYandex)
                .then(function (response) {

                    let textoTraduzido = response.data.text[0];
                    return textoTraduzido;

                })
                .catch(function (erro) {
                    return "erro na categoria";
                })


    return res;
}
```

A função não espera a promise para retornar o valor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você está usando a sintaxe do async/await de maneira incorreta. O correto seria:

```
try {
    const response = await axios.get(urlYandex);

    return response.data.text[0];
} catch(error) {
    return error;
}
```

Caso for usar o then/catch da Promise retornada pelo axios, remova a sintaxe do async/await, que foi feita exatamente para tornar o código menos verboso.

Fico à disposição, até mais.

Comment: Não diria que usar o `await` como ele fez está "errado"... Afinal, o `then` está retornando outra `Promise`.